# Confusion about feedback resistor values for buck converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck

I'm making my first voltage regulation first with a buck converter, but I'm having some trouble making sense of the following datasheet. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps560200.pdf

So I've made the circuit with the recommended components values given in Table 2 in section 8.2.2.2. Now I expect the table to give me the right results, but I did also gave equation 2 a try to calculate the `R2` value.

I want an output of 3.3V, and I use the 20kΩ as recommended in the table for `R1`. This makes me end up with `R2` needing a resistance of 6400Ω (=20000*0.8/(3.3-0.8)), but if I compare that with the 61.9kΩ recommended, then I get really confused as to how they arrived at those values, as those two values are nowhere near each other. Also, the equation of `R2` seems to be inverted proportional to the values recommended in the table.

I would really appreciate an answer on what I'm doing wrong, as I, by default, assume I am as it's my first switching voltage regulation design.

Comment: Table is correct, equation mixed up R1 and R2.

Comment: Well spotted @LarsHankeln. Thank you!

Comment: @techbech You can also try www.syncbuck.com to calculate standard divider resistor values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table 2 recommends that R2 be 20 k-ohms throughout, then gives you R1 values.  This is backwards from how their equation 2 calculates it.

I get 62.5 k-ohms for R1 given 3.3V out and R2 = 20 k-ohms.  I'm not sure where *that* discrepancy is, but it's a lot closer to their table.

Basically -- make the voltage divider that feeds the \$V_{sense}\$ pin such that \$V_{sense}\$ sees 0.8V when the output is what you want.